# Is there any known performance limit in Symfony2 form component?

Tags: performance, forms, symfony

I've this schema structure:

- **Report** -> id, forecasts
- **Forecast** -> id, user_id, bricks, products
- **Brick** -> id, region, plans
- **Plan** -> id, area, targets
- **Target** -> id, product, valueA, valueB, comments
- **Comment** -> id, target, user, message, createdAt
- **Product** -> id, forecast, targets, valueC
- **Region** -> id, name, bricks
- **Area** -> id, name, plans

And I'm editing a **Forecast** with my custom FormType.

ForecastGridType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('bricks', 'collection', array(
        'type' => 'forecast_grid_brick',
    ));

    $builder->add('products', 'collection', array(
        'type' => 'forecast_grid_product',
    ));
}
```

ForecastGridBrickType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('plans', 'collection', array(
        'type' => 'forecast_grid_plan',
    ));
}
```

ForecastGridProductType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('valueC', 'number', array(
            'autocomplete'  => false,
            'attr'          => array(
                'class' => 'grid-mini positive-integer'
            ),
        ));
}
```

ForecastGridPlanType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('targets', 'collection', array(
        'type' => 'forecast_grid_target',
    ));
}
```

ForecastGridTargetType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('valueA', 'number', array(
            'autocomplete'  => false,
            'attr'          => array(
                'class' => 'grid-mini positive-integer'
            )
        ))
        ->add('valueB', 'number', array(
            'autocomplete'  => false,
            'attr'          => array(
                'class' => 'grid-mini positive-integer'
            )
        ))
        ->add('comments', 'collection', array(
            'type'          => 'forecast_grid_comment',
            'allow_add'     => true,
            'allow_delete'  => false
        ));
}
```

ForecastGridCommentType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('message', 'text', array(
            'autocomplete'  => false,
            'required'      => false,
            'attr'          => array(
                'class'       => 'grid-mini',
                'disabled'    => 'disabled',
            ),
        ));
}
```

Ofcourse all the form types have `data_class` set to the corresponding class, I just didn't include the other methods to make this as short as possible.

Creating and viewing the form is not a problem and symfony deals with it quickly (under 0.5s). The problem is when I send the form:

```
public function updateAction($id)
{
    $forecast = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AcmeForecastBundle:Forecast')
        ->find($id);

    $this->checkCredentials('canEditForecastGrid(object)', $forecast);

    if (!$forecast) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The Acme\ForecastBundle\Entity\Forecast with id $id can't be found");
    }

    $form = $this->createForm('forecast_grid', $forecast);

    $form->handleRequest($this->getRequest()); // this makes my server hang

    echo 'This part is never reached'; exit;
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // etc
```

So.. in the POST I have:

```
[forecast_grid] => array(
    [products] => array(
        // contains 6 products each with 1 field: valueC, example below
        [0] => array(
            [valueC] => "X"
        )
    ),
    [bricks] => array(
        // contains 10 bricks, each with 1 field: plans, example below
        [0] => array(
            [plans] => array(
                // contains various amount of plans
                // some bricks have 2 plans, some have 30
                // all together there are approx 120 plans in the form
                [0] => array(
                    [targets] => array(
                        // contains 6 targets, 1 for each product
                        // each with 3 fields: valueA, valueB, comments, example:
                        [0] => array(
                             [valueA] = "Y",
                             [valueB] = "Z",
                             [comments] => array(
                                 // contains  1 or 0 comments,
                                 // only one (new) comment is submitted
                                 // existing comments don't need to be 
                                 // submitted becouse of "allow_delete" => false
                                 // option, example below:
                                 [0] => array(
                                     [message] => "My comment"
                                 )
))))))))
```

So.. we have 120 plans x 6 targets x 2 fields => 1440 fields, plus 6 products x 1 field = 6 fields, plus (maximum) 120 plans x 6 targets x 1 comment = 720 fields.

Which gives us 2166 fields. Now is that too much?

I've done some tests and Instatiationg 10000 stdClasses, assingning 20 fields and running preg_match on each field... instantanious. I know that the framework does more than that, but that amount of fields shouldn't be a problem to PHP I think.

It's hard to debug, when the only thing you get is max_execution_time error (no symfony profiler :<) or your apache2 hanging.

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in (...)/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php on line 943

My question is:

- is trying to submit that many fields in one go an error (symfony2 form component was never built to handle such tasks)?
- or symfony2 **should** deal with that form without problems, meaning that the root of the error lies somewhere else (doctrine2 hydration?).. if so.. where could it be and how could I test if thats the case?

Some folks suggested I use AJAX to submit each plan (with 6 targets) individually. I will probably do that, becouse I have not much time left, but I'd still be interested in knowing the answer -> are there any known performance limits to symfony2 form component?

Comment: Did you set the max execution time to a higher level to see if the code in the end works properly? Also the problem is the nesting of forms. Not the number of entities. Is there any possibility to move some of them into a different form / window / request?

Comment: Well, the nesting is only to make rendering the form easier. I could make a simple form with 2000 targets and 6 products (no nesting). You think this could give a performance boost?

Comment: No. What I mean is more like one form for e.g. `products` and `grids` and add the other entities in a separate form later

Comment: Unfortunately, this data grid has to be edited in one form. It only makes sense for the user when he can compare data in the grid. Splitting the form is not an option.

Comment: Okay. As I said the nesting should give you performance problems. If it is too slow use `Ajax` as suggested.

Comment: I've set the maximum time limit to 5 minutes and this allowed me to see, that I had a few minor errors (typos mainly). After fixing them, removeing fetch="EAGER" from associations and clearing the cache.. the loading time went down to 16s. So I'm "almost there" and it seems that in the end Symfony2 can handle such forms.

Comment: The form component does do considerable processing.  It might be interesting to try retrieving an array from doctrine instead of a graph of objects.  On the Doctrine side if you implement change tracking notify (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/cookbook/implementing-the-notify-changetracking-policy.html) then the persist/flush process will speed up considerably assuming that relatively few changes are made during any given request.  Won't help with the form component but it will help with the overall time.

Comment: But I must say that from a user interface perspective, a form with 2000+ elements is not a good idea.  Do they really need to be able to change 2000 things in one request?  How could they keep track of what they are doing?  Hate to say it but the correct solution to this problem is to change the user interface.  At a minimum you can break it up into two forms (products and bricks).

Comment: And one final note, with a project like this, automated testing is a must.  If you have not already then take the time to set some up.

Comment: Thanks for tips Cerad, I'll definately try it. As for user interface, there are some requirements I can't change (unless it can't be done). The client given two choices: 15+ seconds of "saveing" time vs. from broken down into pieces chose the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After considering and testing many approaches I decided to go with AJAX and save items one at a time. I've managed to get the save 2000+ fields action time down to 5s (which proves how much symfony is capable of, nice!), and I believe there is still room for performance improvements, **but** to do that I've had to:

- raise the php.ini and apache2.conf limits of max inputs, max execution time, max upload size, etc. to extremely high values
- disable many [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) rules (which weakens server protection against various kinds of attacks)
- change application logic and database schema to less readable/maintainable (but with better performance)
- spend way too much time working on and testing such simple functionality

My conclusion is: it can be done, but it's not worth the trouble. Better do it with AJAX.

And to anwser the question: yes, there is a limit. It depends on many variables, but in general, if you're trying to save 1000+ fields at a time, you should expect trouble.

Comment: Hi loostro, I have a Collection of 200 forms, but I do not need to submitt all of them, do you know if there is a possibility to parse only some of those forms from the collection?